# How to create a full page layout using pure semantic html + css

Tags: css, html

I have this html body:

```
    <body>
     <header>
     </header>
     <main>
     </main>
     <footer>
     </footer>
    </body>
```

How can I make the footer sticky to the bottom in a way that it does NOT overlay the main part if this main part is bigger than the viewport of the browser?
I want to use only css for layout and no additional html elems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```css
html{
  height : 100%;
}
body{  
  height : 100%;
  min-height : 100%;
}
header{  
  background :red;min-height : 10%;
  float :left;
  width : 100%;
}

main{  
 background :black;
  min-height : 80%;
  float :left;
  width : 100%;
  color : #ffffff;
}
footer{
  min-height : 10%;
  float :left;
  width : 100%;
  background :blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <header >
     qwe
     </header>
     <main>
     qwe
     </main>
     
     <footer>
     footer
     </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't link to external examples when you can make such an example here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment. External links may become dead after a period of time and then your answer would become useless.

Comment: Next time I will take care

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways to do so, please take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

But here a quick todo by simple using FLEX:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
    <body>
      <header>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <p>footer text</p>
        <p>footer text</p>
        <p>footer text</p>
      </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: @Ickbinet awesome, thanks, please vote for my answer and also make sure you marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Flexbox`. See this for [a complete guide to flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Check out this fiddle for a working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/9fr83575/

Using `flex-grow: 1;` on your `main` will fill the remaining space.

> **flex-grow** 
>   This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It
>   dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container
>   the item should take up.
>
> If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the
>   container will be distributed equally to all children. If one of the
>   children has a value of 2, the remaining space would take up twice as
>   much space as the others (or it will try to, at least).